# Upgrading Ubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10, but the process was terminated, what now?

Tags: apt, upgrade, 18.10

I am noob with Ubuntu and i was trying to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10 with the command `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and everything was running smoothly, but at some point of the upgrade i saw that my terminal was shutdown by itself... I am trying to do this locally, not by ssh and now i dont know what to do... I cant restart my computer as it says

> Incorrect permission on /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkid-agent-helper-1 (needs to be setuid root)

and i have two options `Cancel` or 'Authenticate` and when i click on authenticate nothing happens...

Also when i try to run `sudo apt dist-upgrade` again i got this error

> E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

What i have to do now?

Comment: Just reboot. And FYI `dist-upgrade` does NOT upgrade the Ubuntu version, it fully updates the current version. And that command probably should be used now (and since years ago) because it was "replaced" by `full-upgrade` since, I think, 16.04.

Comment: `sudo reboot` dosent work...

Comment: Now I can't boot my computer anymore and I am getting error... 'PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key'

Comment: The command to bump your release (from 18.04 to 18.10) is `do-release-upgrade`; which modifies sources for you, and performs a 'dist-upgrade' type upgrade (BUT in a specific order to avoid problems with particularly python)...   did you modify your sources & then try to dist-upgrade to the next version??   Ubuntu is not Debian (where 'dist-upgrade' performs that function).  'dist-upgrade' is just an upgrade with fewer restrictions  (read the man page, *dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a few hours i manage to work it out and was able to fix the broken upgrade. First of all i was not able to reboot the system so i had to do it using the hard reboot (by pressing and holding the power button on my laptop). Then i was not able to boot the system again.

- I had to go to the restore mode (holding `Shift` when system is booting) and then to go `Run terminal as root` (or something like that)
- Then I had to connect to the internet and because my internet was not working i had to edit the file `/etc/resolv.conf` and place the following `nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`
- Then I ran `aptitude` (because my apt was going me error i had to run `dpkg --configure -a`, but this was not helpful, so both `apt` and `dpkg` were not working for me), then i press `g` and then again `g` (twice) and aptitude start to download and upgrade all the packages that weren't upgrade because the process was stopped when the terminal shut down
- Then i quit aptitude and run `apt update` and `apt upgrade`. Upgrade was not working again so i run `dpkg --configure -a` and this time dpkg worked its magic and then i run `apt upgrade` and if you see everything executing without any errors you are good to go and u can boot your system in a normal way and everything should work fine.

Hope i can help to all the people that were interrupted after starting the upgrading process of Ubuntu