# error trying to install anything

Tags: dpkg

Well, i jumped over to Lubuntu, and I'm on a fresh install of it... but I wanted to go ahead and install elementary to a flash drive and check it out, but cant because when I use terminal to install `mkusb`, I get this error:

```
dps@chris-pc:~$ sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
[sudo] password for dps: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

Also, when I try to install anything via the software center (discovery) it says:

```
   PolicyKit Error
   Incorrect permissions on /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1 (needs to be setuid root)
```

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process) && https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari

Comment: but thats not my question. im sorry

Comment: im trying  few different things from the suggested answer, to no avail. im about to do a fresh install, one more time. thank you

Comment: The links is pomsky's comment are relevant to the first issue you mentioned and possibly related to the second issue as well. What could be happening is that the system is itself checking for updates using the same tools you're trying to use. The result is that certain system files are locked until the system completes its work. Read about unattended upgrades. The way I deal with the situation is just to try again later :)

Comment: And if you've just made a new installation, there will be quite a few updates available straightaway because all updates from the date the OS was released to the moment you installed the OS will be pending. These updates will also have security updates which, by default, are prioritized.

Comment: nice! i did a new installation and so far so good. im going to let the updates download and finish installing this time.