# Canon printer not printing

Tags: canon

I recently upgraded ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04. I am trying to get my canon printer going again. I have it installed and  when I print, it says 'printing', then 'printing complete', but doesn't print. Then I get Problem detected pop up with cancel/report option. In my var/crash folder I have a file named cnijlgmon3.7.crash. I cannot delete the crash file, but obviously it is a canon driver file with cnij at beginning. Wondering where to go from here.

Comment: Using Synaptic PM I do not have said file installed.

Comment: I tried to install apport retrace to retrace the crash file but I get an error:" E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?"

Comment: "Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open" is a related problem I think, and I have tried various things from this site to 'fix'.

Answer (score 0):

"E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)"
This is a common problem when Ubuntu is checking for updates while attempting to use apt in a terminal. Check out this previous question for more info [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1109982/1029525)

Comment: OK, so the /var/lib/dpkg/lock issue might not be my printing issue. I am trying to add my canon mg5220 printer. I downloaded the mg5200 series software with synaptic. I have been trying to add the printer as a network printer and it says printing, printing complete but nothing happens. I can add it with device URI, but don't know the URI to enter. I did try ipp://printer/localhost:631 but no joy.

Comment: Do you have cups-backend-bjnp package installed?

Comment: I did not have cups backend. I installed it now. I will delete my printer and add it again, still not sure of URI while adding.

Comment: SOLVED: Must have been missing cups backend, Thanks da kingpin! I selected Network printer and it found my Canon MG 5200 series,

Comment: Happy I could provide some assistance.