# I have two different versions of Ubuntu downloaded on the same computer. How can I remove the older version

Tags: apt, dpkg

I recently just upgraded Ubuntu from 16.04 to 19.1. When I tried using 19.1 it got all sorts of bugs which I think might be because of the older version of Ubuntu. This is one of the errors I encountered.

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Is there a way to remove the older version of Ubuntu(16.04) from my computer? Thanks!

Comment: 19.1 == 19.10 ?? How did you upgrade? There is no direct path from 16.04 to 19.10.

Comment: not direct means there is afaik no supported path besides 16.04 -> 18.04 -> 18.10 -> 19.04 -> 19.10, but as 18.10 and 19.04 are not supported anymore, I doubt this is easily possible. Everything else is a hack. And I would suggest you make a backup of your files and install from scratch, it will be much less hazzle then fixing your issues. You may want to wait a week for 20.04 to come out or go for the beta which seems to be pretty stable ... (but is not supported on askubuntu until the final release)

Comment: Your error reads like you tried a command which requires elevated (ie. `sudo`) privileges but used your user credentials.  Please clarify your release though, there was no Ubuntu release in 2019-January (19.1; Ubuntu releases are *year.month* specifying release time, making EOL easy to calculate).

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to install Ubuntu 19.10 by downloading it once again using a different partition on my hard drive than the original Ubuntu(16.04) that I had downloaded it on. Now considering it I should have just wiped my drive when I was given the option when downloading Ubuntu(19.10)(I had already backed up some of my files in case something went wrong). Thanks again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari)