# MPEG-4 AAC decoder, and the H.264 decoder

Tags: apt, 20.04, bash

I just reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and got error messages trying to play Mpeg videos.  I read the instructions in "How to install the MPEG-4 AAC decoder and the H.264 decoder?" and ran a terminal for:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

The process ran as it seems it should and then ended with a EULA imposed on the terminal.  "OK" was shown at the bottom of the text, but I couldn't figure out how to accept the EULA.  After several tries, I, evidently foolishly, exited the terminal, ignoring the warning that a process was running and I would kill it if I exited.  Of course, the decoders aren't installed/working.  I tried to run it again, and then the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec58 libav-tools ffmpeg
```

and got the following screen both times:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libavcodec58 libav-tools ffmpeg
[sudo] password for ij: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 30816 (apt-get)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

I just looked at my System Monitor, but am unable to determine what process(es) are the one(s) that are causing the problem.  There are two "lib" processes at the top of the list.

Am I screwed?  I just spent two days reinstalling 20.04 and tweaking everything.  I'm a real noobie and not comfortable with anything but clear line-by-line commands. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari)

Answer (score 1):

So I killed the process with

> sudo kill 30816

That allowed me to restart the computer without the warning that a process was running and that I needed admin credentials to shut down.  I then found another website

> https://linuxconfig.org/unable-to-play-the-file-missing-decoder-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa

that offered the commands:

> sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras

and

> apt install libdvdnav4 libdvd-pkg gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly

Running those did result in a message superimposed on the terminal, but hitting return accepted the "OK" and continued and eventually finished the installation. The mpegs now play.

Answer (score 0):

The EULA screen is very old-school. Press Tab to move fields and Spacebar to activate (maybe enter will work too).