# Wine32 Missing Dependencies Won't Install

Tags: apt, wine

I noticed that WINE Windows applications do not respond and it appears to be a missing dependency. Wine was working but suddenly it wasn't. I tried purging WINE and reinstalling it but when I run winecfg, I still get an error that it needs wine32 but it will not install:

```
sudo apt-get install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This seems to imply that libwine is not installed but when I try to install it, I get a message that it is already installed and is the latest version:

```
sudo apt-get install libwine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libwine is already the newest version (5.0-3ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
```

Running`dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` does not show anything missing. I also ran `sudo apt install libwine:i386` and still get unmet dependencies which I will look into shortly.

```
sudo apt install libwine:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwine:i386 : Depends: libfaudio0:i386 (>= 19.06.07) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

apt-cache policy gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.16.2-4
  Version table:
     1.16.2-4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:
  Installed: 1.16.2-4
  Candidate: 1.16.2-4
  Version table:
 *** 1.16.2-4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

This shows that gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 is not installed but it does not install either.

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.40) but it is not going to be installed
                                  Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.16.2) but it is not going to be installed
                                  Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.16.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After trying the things above, I tried again to install Win32 and now get this error:

```
sudo apt-get install wine32
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 52585 (apt)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

Comment: sudo apt install libwine:i386  try this

Comment: "*impossible situation*" means that you have installed Wine packages that are incompatible with your current release of Ubuntu. Usually that means you have installed wrong-version or non-Ubuntu packages. Purge them. Delete the sources that provided them. Then install Wine from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Ubuntu itself chose the WINE version to install as is done with modern versions. In the past one had to specify it but no more. I also tried `sudo apt install libwine:i386` as suggested and appended the question with the result but I have not yet tried to install these dependencies mentioned in the error.

Comment: Please add `apt-cache policy gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good` compare the versions are the same.

Comment: I added the output of `apt-cache policy gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good`.

Comment: Pardon , my fault.  `apt-cache policy gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base` the other package I ask for is only recommend. With `apt-cache policy packegename  packagename :i386` you can see if the versions are different. Another ẁay is to install aptitude and ask `aptitude why-not packagename` If you have no packages on your system from some ppa's it could also be a mirror problem. try the main server.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I made the change and corrected my question but it made no difference. Also, I am already using the main server for packages too.

Comment: Try putting all the :i386 packages on the same install line.  That sometimes handles multiple dependencies better.

Comment: Trying them on one line, there is now a cache error `Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 52585 (apt)..` that repeats over and over.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [See terminal text. 'Waiting for cache lock' error. How to fix? I'm on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352416/see-terminal-text-waiting-for-cache-lock-error-how-to-fix-im-on-ubuntu-21) and [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)/](https://askubuntu.com/q/1109982/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)