# Vivaldi Browser is not installing in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, vivaldi

I had Vivaldi on this computer when it ran 16.04. After installing Focal, I downloaded the browser. When I click on install, an Ubuntu Software window tells me:

```
Unable to install vivaldi-stable:
E: Could not get lock/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held
by process 4318 (synaptic).
```

I don't know how to find that in Synaptic. (Software is up to date.) I am inexperienced with computers and often have difficulty following instructions. A detailed step-by-step solution would be appreciated.

Comment: `synaptic` is a package manager you likely have open in a window on your screen; it can be used to add packages thus is locking the system until you close the `synaptic` window.  Only use one package-manager/software-store at a time.

Comment: Right, just close Synaptic, and try again in the terminal.

Comment: Synaptic is closed. What should I type in the terminal?

Comment: When I pasted lock/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend I got no such file or folder. When I pasted the file name given in  the install window I got "syntax error".

Comment: I couldn't find Vivaldi in the software offered here, so I downloaded it from the web. Was that wrong?

Comment: After repeated attempts, it finally installed on clicking the install button. I don't know why it didn't work before, but this time I got the installing progress bar for a minute or two, and then it opened in the applications window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari) and [See terminal text. 'Waiting for cache lock' error. How to fix? I'm on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352416/)