# How to unlock dpkg after cancelling 'configure secure boot'?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I was installing OBS, and ran the following command:

```
sudo apt install v4l2loopback-dkms
```

As I was doing other things, I messed up, and when I returned to the terminal, I used CTRL+C on the 'configure secure boot' screen (without selecting/typing a password):

[Secure boot screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmZYH.png)

I am now unable to resume/install anything else, as I get the following error:

```
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 20212 (apt)
```

Which is understandable, as process 20212 is:

```
root       20212  0.0  0.4  93844 71696 ?        T    10:46   0:01 apt install v4l2loopback-dkms
```

Reading about the issue, I am obviously hesitant to restart/kill this process - is there a way for me to return to 'configure secure boot' as the MOK was already generated? I am afraid if I restart it will mess something up!

Thank you!

Comment: @user535733 as above, I see the following:
`root       20212  0.0  0.4  93844 71696 ?        T    10:46   0:01 apt install v4l2loopback-dkms`

However, I guess the question then is, how do I unlock dpkg? Am I OK to just kill pid 20212?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari)