# can't install anything in software-install

Tags: download-manager

can't install anything in ubuntu with software-install.such as java18
I don't know, what to do.
Please help.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCUe1.png)

Comment: The message suggests that the system believes that apt is already running and working on something else.

Comment: In case you are not installing anything, just reboot the computer and try again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari)