# Unable to update through terminal by typing sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates

Its is showing the following error listed below please help.

```
sudo apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 40669 (apt-get)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Comment: This might help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari    It’s not an identical question, but I suspect the most popular answer will give you useful suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari)

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is another apt-get process. Try rebooting and running `sudo apt update`. Rebooting usually kills the other process. If you are using desktop, then make sure there is no other terminal/tab executing another process. If you're not manually cancelling `sudo apt-get update` using ^C, it should continue displaying `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 40669 (apt-get)` every second. If it isn't, then it's another weird error.