# Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 5847 (aptd)

Tags: error-handling, github, urban-terror

I was trying to install git in my Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

- After using "**sudo apt update**" command.
- I used "**sudo apt upgrade -y**" cmd.
- Then it displayed this message -> "**Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 5847 (aptd)**"

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another window/terminal waiting for you to respond to a question?  Alternatively it could be system background updates, but that will resolve itself shortly anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Answer (score 1):

Error **Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend** says that your operation `sudo apt update` probally is not finished. Check for process with id 5847 by running in terminal `ps -p 5847`. You will see what process prevents you from upgrading. You can wait until it finishes, but if you are sure that it is a mistake, you can restart your laptop or pc and lock error will disappear, so you can continue installing git. But I strongly recommend to wait until previous operation is finished.